# Ionic 2/3 - ion-datetime - setting max is changing a default year to its max

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, datepicker, ionic2, momentjs

in Ionic 2/3 app I want to use ion-datetime and its datepicker component.
Its working almost fine.

I have two dates - start and end, which are binded with my controller properties. In my controller I also set min and max values for both dates.

Problem is  - when I set a max attribute for any of dates, default date in datepicker is set to its year (for example, if I set max to 2020, default date in datepicker will be January 1 2020). **How can I force it to display default date as today?**). It always uses first of january of max year as default.

Screenshot example: I've set my max date to 25/08/2018. When I open datepicker, default date is january 1st 2018.
When I change my max date do 25/08/2020, also will be 1st of january, 2020.
This is not expected behaviour.
[image: initial date when max is 25/08/2018]

My template:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label stacked>Start:</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime [max]="startMax" [min]="startMin"
 displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="start" 
(ionChange)="startDateChanged($event)"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label stacked>End:</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime [min]="endMin" [max]="endMax" 
displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" 
[(ngModel)]="end"
(ionChange)="endDateChanged($event)"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

My controller:

```
export class NewRequestStep2 {
  start: any;
  end: any;
  startMin: any;
  startMax: any;
  endMin: any;
  endMax: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.startMin = moment().format();
    this.startMax = moment().add(1, 'year').format();
    this.endMin = this.startMin;
    this.endMax = this.startMax;
  }



startDateChanged(event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(this.start);
    console.log(this.end);
    if (this.end) {
      if (moment(this.start) > moment(this.end)) {
        this.end = null;
        console.log('Invalid end');
      }
    }
  }

  endDateChanged(event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(this.start);
    console.log(this.end);
    if (this.start) {
      if (moment(this.start) > moment(this.end)) {
        this.start = null;
        console.log('Invalid start');
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: have you well read the docs?
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/

Comment: I thought so :) I cant find solution

Comment: did you try to change data format that moment returns?

Comment: @Microsmsm Why should I do this? I am returning ISO-8601, which is enough. Date format is correct, problem is that ionic automatically set my end date as default (when end date attribute is set) which I don't want. I think you didn't understand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to set it only when datepicker shows up.

Here is working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0KJ7xR?p=preview).

**HTML:**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary">Select Date</ion-label>
      <ion-input placeholder="Text Input" [value]="dataInicial | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'" (click)="open()"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item no-lines hidden="true">
      <ion-datetime #datePicker displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" (ionCancel)="this.dataInicial  = null" [(ngModel)]="dataInicial" doneText="Feito" cancelText="Cancelar" [max]="maxDate">
      </ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular'; 

@Component({
     selector: 'page-home',
     templateUrl: 'app/home.page.html'
 })
 export class HomePage {

     appName = 'Ionic App';
     dataInicial: Date;
     maxDate: string;

     constructor(public neavController: NavController) {}
     @ViewChild('datePicker') datePicker;
     open() {
         if (!this.dataInicial) {
             this.dataInicial = new Date().toJSON().split('T')[0];
             setTimeout(() => {
                 this.datePicker.open();
             }, 50)
         } else {
             this.datePicker.open();
         }

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `start` and `end` variables to the current date when the component is initialised:

```
export class NewRequestStep2 {
  start: string = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  end: string = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  startMin: any;
  startMax: any;
  endMin: any;
  endMax: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.startMin = moment().format();
    this.startMax = moment().add(1, 'year').format();
    this.endMin = this.startMin;
    this.endMax = this.startMax;
  }



startDateChanged(event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(this.start);
    console.log(this.end);
    if (this.end) {
      if (moment(this.start) > moment(this.end)) {
        this.end = null;
        console.log('Invalid end');
      }
    }
  }

  endDateChanged(event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(this.start);
    console.log(this.end);
    if (this.start) {
      if (moment(this.start) > moment(this.end)) {
        this.start = null;
        console.log('Invalid start');
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will set the input values, I want them to be empty when user opens the page. Is it possible to set it only when datepicker shows up?

Comment: @dease should be possible, however the field will then be populated when the user clicks the input.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem like you. In my case I have two date selectors and when I select start date on first second should starts from selected date. I fixed that problem by adding set timeout in on data change in first date selector.

```
onFromDateChange() {
  setTimeout(t => {
    this.dateTimeToMin = this.regForm.controls['startDate']._value;
  }, 100);
}
```